# Writing to a file if it's being created for first time

Tags: c++

I want to write Some Header to my file only the first time it's being created.  The file name is report .txt

My attempt so far-->

```
   if(ifstream("report.txt")){
       printf("The file already exists");

   }

 else
 {
     printf("file is created for first time\n");
    ofstream resfile("report.txt");
       resfile<<"MaxPackets\tInterval\tPacketSize\ttimeFirstTPacket"<<endl;

 }
```

I'm getting the output "file is created for first time" when it happens but nothing is being written to it . Sorry all it's being written to the file after i comment out all the code that is present after it.

The code after the above lines is -->

```
   ofstream outfile("report.txt");
    while(getline(infile,data)) 
     {
         istringstream res(data);
              string word;
              int flag;

         if(line==0){

              outfile<<"1000\t0.01\t64\t";

              flag=0;

              while(res>>word){

                  if(flag==1)
                    outfile<<word<<endl;

                flag++;
              }


         }





         line++;

     }

     outfile.close();
```

But how to rectify it?? please help

Comment: are you sure you are looking in the right place on the file system? Put an absolute path in there

Comment: What if you can't create the file? Have you checked that the file is created properly? And how (and when and where) do you check if data has been written to it?

Comment: Yaa , i'm sure about the path no problem there

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me. Maybe you have a permission error.

Comment: Could you use `stat()` to check if the file exists instead of opening it with `ifstream`? I feel like `ifstream` may block writes to the file (though I don't know enough about C++ internals to be sure).

Comment: Use this code to test that it is opened or not:if (myfile.is_open()) {...}

Comment: I think the "MaxPackets\tInterval\tPacketSize\ttimeFirstTPacket" is not getting wriiten due to something i did below it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the file for output twice, and the second time is overwriting what you wrote the first time. You can either open it only once, or you can open it in append mode the second time:

```
ofstream outfile("report.txt", std::ios::app);
```

This will make it append to the end of the file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Instead of `ifstream` use `tellg` immediately after opening the file to find out if it is empty. (If tellg returns 0, write the header before data, else proceed directly to appending)